# How do I zoom into the page of an html and css file?

Tags: html, css, web

My page looks better in the zoom scale of 150% and I want all users to look at it that way. Is there a CSS code snippet that I could use to make the default viewing by 150%?

How can i automatically adjust the zoom by %.

Comment: If you used font-size in `rem` throughout the entire CSS design process, you don't need anything but just change the base font-size in one place (html, body). If you used `px`... well, I feel sorry and you've learnt something. Forcing a n% browser zoom is not possible using JS - this is specifically controlled by the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By far the most trivial way is to make all of your fixed values in CSS 50% bigger than they are currently. You may backup your CSS before increasing the values to not be lost in the process.

There is also a special value of `viewport` meta-tag called [`initial-scale`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag#viewport_basics) that you can set in your HTML, but unfortunately, it doesn't work on desktop, only on mobile devices, based on my tests (I've used Chrome DevTools to enable mobile device emulation).

You may be tempted to apply [`transform: scale()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) to the root element of your HTML, but please don't do that, it won't be responsive, as `transform` property doesn't affect document flow.